# Store Mirth logs in Database

Tags: mirth

I just started using mirth. I am able to send messages from source to destination. But now I want to store the mirth logs in an Oracle database.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

[image: The screenshot of the logs that I want to store]

Comment: Are you referring to the actual logged server output that shows up on the bottom of the main dashboard? That can be configured in the log4j.properties file.

The channel message history in your screenshot is stored in the main mirth database. The Mirth database can be configured in the mirth.properties file.

If you want to send message output to an Oracle DB, you can do that with a Database Writer destination or in Javascript.

Comment: @TonyG-R Will try this. Thanks

Comment: If you clarify your question you can get a better answer.